# Numeric collection name expression not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have declared numeric collection names in mongodb. eg 98004 etc. When I try to query the data with find or findOne I get the following error.

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'findOne' of undefined.
```

I have tried following expressions, but they don't seem to work.

```
db["98004"].findOne()
db['98004'].findOne()
```

But when I use `db.getCollection("98004").findOne()`, it works. Does anybody know why is this happening? I thought `db["98004"].findOne()` expression should work.

Thanks

Comment: JS will auto convert string encapsulated numeric indexes to integer ones causing you to search for index 98004 of the db array/object.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand you. Do you mean that this expression db[98007].findOne() will work?

Comment: No, because of how magics work in JS, only strictly string indexes will work and string indexes not of `help` since that is reserved.

Comment: Though correction: it seems `db['help']` is not actuaslly reserved in that case, only `db.help` is

Comment: There has been a working answer here for several minutes. Why the discussion?

Comment: @NeilLunn He mentions the use of `getCollection()` in his question. He is not looking for a work around, he is looking for an explanation

Comment: @Sammaye It was only edited after I posted the answer. There is actually a JIRA sitting around about this somewhere. Not that I expect a resolution soon. It's just the shell anyhow. In real drivers you use the method that fetches the collection by name.

Comment: @Sammaye Thanks for your explanation. I am kinda new to Javascript/Mongodb world

Comment: @NeilLunn , I actually had already tried getCollection() much before posting, I just didn't understand why db["98004"].findOne() wasn't working.

Comment: As I said. "This is shell behavior". Don't expect everything you think to be logical to JavaScript objects to apply to how the mongodb shell does it. Whether you already tried it and did not mention it is not the point. The only way to do it is exactly as described.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method for this:

```js
db.getCollection("98004").findOne();
```

And basically present in every driver. The shell syntax is just a helper.